# Toggling the centre dot

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I draw a circle, and in the middle of the circle is a dot. This is the centre dot.
I would like to use the line tool to draw a line from the centre. When my cursor is above the centre dot, the Line tool changes automatically into a Move tool. Instead of drawing a line, when I click and drag, it moves the circle.
In the Attributes panel there is an option to turn the centre dot on and off. **This has no effect on anything**. The dot does not disappear, from circle objects, from line objects, from polygons. It is broken.
I have reset my preferences. I have installed the latest version (at time of writing this is 26.5). My current workaround is to lock the object, then draw the line. I’m suppressing the urge to rant here, but many things in Illustrator that were once very trivial seem to be extremely convoluted. Am I missing an option? How do I toggle that dot on and off?

Answer (score 1):

Deselect the circle object and the line should draw